# cannot find -lGL on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt-creator, qt5

Did somebody succseed to compile a qtcreator qt project on Ubuntu 13.10? I did see answers on other environment up until 13.04, but it seams the packages have changed and I can install any of the mentioned packages. I need to know what dev package needs to be installed to satisfy the missing link library.

Answer (score 1):

> I can install any of the mentioned packages

Do you mean you **can't** install any of the mentioned packages? Why not?

Anyhow. You need two things here:

1. figuring out what's the file name you're looking for
2. figuring out how to locate the package containing that file name

Given that you're looking for a *shared library*, and you're passing `-lGL` to the linker, then the file name you're looking for is **libGL.so**.

Now, there are two strategies for figuring out which Ubuntu package contains what:

- Using apt-file:

  1. install it: `apt-get install apt-file`
  2. search for the file `apt-file search libGL.so`
- Using the online package search:

  1. point your browser to http://packages.ubuntu.com/
  2. scroll to the "Search the contents of packages" section
  3. put **libGL.so** in the search field, and select your version (saucy) and architecture

Both of these ways will return three families of packages:

1. mesa-related packages
2. nvidia-related packages
3. flgrx-related packages

The last two are there because NVidia and AMD provide vendor-specific libGL.so overrides. But the one you're looking for is actually the first. So just install it.

Answer (score 1):

Check `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` and `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so`, they should point to existing files.